# Backbone unable to start?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm getting started with backbone.js...
but couldn't get it to work at all.

```
 <script src="Libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Libraries/backbone.js"></script><script src="Libraries/Underscore.js"></script>

 <script>
   $(function(){    
 window.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
       });
  });
 </script>
```

And on Chrome, the error log says: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined..and was initiated by Backbone.Model.extend...why?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load Underscore first, as Backbone is dependent on it (you can't drive your car without the engine) - try:

```
<script src="Libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Libraries/Underscore.js"></script>
<script src="Libraries/backbone.js"></script>
```

also, just to be safe, put everything in a window "on load" function to make sure everything is loaded -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
});
```

Comment: `$(function(){...}` - is jquery `onload` function

Comment: jquery can be assumed because backbone has a dependency on it.